# array filtering based on multiple enum selected conditions in swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, filter

On tapping filter button in my app, i display below filters to user.
[image]

I have array of struct - Site and I need to filter the array based on enum selected by user.

It involves both AND and OR condition. If user selects underconstruction only then filter array and if user selects both - underconstruction and fullyconstrcution then filter array. Same case applies to Size also.

Below is code :

```
 struct Site {
    var name :String = ""
    var sitestate: [State] = []
    var sitesize:[Size] = []
    var city :String = ""
    var country :String = ""
}

enum State : Int, CaseIterable {
        case underConstruction = 0
        case fullyConstructed
}

enum Size : Int, CaseIterable {
        case small = 0
        case big
}

var sites: [Site]?

var a = Site(name: "Mumbai", sitestate: State.fullyConstructed, sitesize: Size.big, city: "Mumbai", country: "India")
var b = Site(name: "Delhi", sitestate: State.underConstruction, sitesize: Size.small, city: "Delhi", country: "India")

sites.append(a)
sites.append(b)
```

Now sites has 2 elements.

```
/// this is works only for single enum selected
let filteredsite = self.sites?.filter {
        $0.underConstruction == State.underConstruction.rawValue
}
```

Storing user selection of state and size in two variables.

```
var selectedState :[State] = []
var selectedSize :[Size] = []
```

I need use these selectedState and selectedSize for filtering the array.

I tried ... single filter which works but not sure how use combination of filters, cases when both enums are selected - how to apply filter ??

Comment: Your code is very hard to understand, in your example you filter on a property that doesn't exists and a Site instance can have multiple values for state and size. How can a site be both small and big for instance? And please clarify what you mean with both AND and OR filtering

Comment: @JoakimDanielson - added 2 elements in sites array, 1 element has size big and other element has size - small. When we need to filter array using both enums selected by user - it should show - both elements in array.

Comment: That code you have added will not compile, please make sure the definition of `Site` is correct because it doesn't looks so to me. And you haven't really explained the AND/OR logic.

Comment: @sia Please check my updated answer.

Comment: It still doesn't compile. Just copy/paste it into Playground, you'll see. `var sitestate: [State] = []var sitestate: [State] = []` can a `Site` be at the same time `.underConstruction` and `. fullyConstructed`? Same question for its `sitesize`. Why array? The `init()` method you used suggest the contrary, which one correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found a probable solution for this. The struct will be like

```
struct Site {
    var name = ""
    var sitestate: State = .underConstruction
    var sitesize: Size = .small
    var city = ""
    var country = ""
}

enum State : Int, CaseIterable {
       case underConstruction = 0
       case fullyConstructed
}

enum Size : Int, CaseIterable {
       case small = 0
       case big
}
```

Initialize the `sites` object like this

```
var sites: [Site] = []
```

and then you can use this

```
 let a = Site(name: "Mumbai", sitestate: State.fullyConstructed, sitesize: Size.big, city: "Mumbai", country: "India")
 let b = Site(name: "Delhi", sitestate: State.underConstruction, sitesize: Size.small, city: "Delhi", country: "India")

 sites.append(a)
 sites.append(b)
    
 let selectedState :[State] = [State.underConstruction]
 let selectedSize :[Size] = [Size.small]
    
  /// this is works only for single enum selected
 let filteredsite = self.sites.filter {
      selectedState.contains($0.sitestate) && selectedSize.contains($0.sitesize)
  }
  print(filteredsite.count) // 1
```

Hope this should work.

Comment: This code doesn't compile and you are only using hardcoded values when filtering.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson hope the updated code should work.

Comment: It compiles now but you should probably check the updates to the question and the comments to it as well.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Thanks for the suggestion. Would you please review the updated answer?

Comment: @FaysalAhmed Swift is a type inferred language `Size.small` is redundant.  `let selectedSize: [Size] = [.small]`. The same applies for the initializer `Site(name: "Mumbai", sitestate: .fullyConstructed, sitesize: .big, city: "Mumbai", country: "India")`

Comment: @LeoDabus Thanks. I just tried to put answer to follow the question. So that my answer will be more clear about to the question.

Comment: @sia - does this solution ..works for u .. u seen to hv ..multiple conditions ?